# Android setHeight of glsurfaceview

Tags: android, height, glsurfaceview

I want to set the Height of glsurfaceview with custom height.
I want that the width is the same of height.
With android:layout_width="fill_parent".
How I do to have width = height = width_of_the_screen  ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the onMeasure and set both parameters of setMeasuredDimension to the received width as seen below:

```
class TouchSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); 
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}
...
```

with a layout as follows:

```
...
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top"
    >
    <se.company.test.TouchSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glSurface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height programatically by using `view.getLayoutParams().height = view.getMeasuredWidth();` The problem is this has to be done after the view has been drawn for the first time, otherwise `measuredWidth` will just return zero. (Assuming you're using openGL), you can be fairly sure that by the time `onDraw` in your Renderer class is called, it is definitely drawn on screen. However, you'd then have to communicate a message between the GL Thread (that calls `onDraw`) and the (main) UI thread, which is the only one allowed to change views' width/height etc